# Payload CMS Deploy With Docker On Digital Ocean App Platform Fails To Pick Up Secret ENV Var

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, payload-cms

I'm trying to run the base website template of the payload CMS on Digital Ocean's App Platform. My build currently fails with the following error:

"a secret key is needed to secure payload"

Which points to it not picking the `PAYLOAD_SECRET` env var. I do have this set in the environment variables section of my app, and can see it is getting picked up in the logs along with my database connection:

```
configuring build-time app environment variables:
DATABASE_URI PAYLOAD_SECRET
```

I'm not very familiar with docker so I'm not sure why this isn't getting picked up during the build.

For reference, here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.8-alpine as base

FROM base as builder

WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM base as runtime

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=dist/payload.config.js

WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json  ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --production
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/build ./build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "dist/server.js"]
```